# Convert the content of JavaFX TextField into Integer

Tags: java, string, javafx, integer, type-conversion

I have a TextField within a GridPane that I simply want to have it's user-typed contents read into an `Integer` that I will then use for multiple (non-double) calculations.

```
TextField userInput = new TextField();

userInput.textProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) -> {
    if (!newValue.matches("\\d*")) {
        userInput.setText(newValue.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
    }
});

sortButton.setOnMousePressed( e -> { 
    int savedValue = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
    int outputMath = savedValue * 3;
    int outputExpo = savedValue * 10;
    int outputQuad = savedValue * 4;
});
```

The listener does a great job of making sure nothing but numbers gets accepted, but those numbers are read as a string that I don't seem able to use for calculations.

The problem child is that the Integer.parseInt(userInput) just doesn't seem to do the trick here. Any advice?

Comment: but you could try other alternatives, like Integer.valueOf()

Answer (score 3):

On this line:

```
int savedValue = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
```

what you are actually doing is to try to parse the variable `userInput` which is a `TextField.`

You should parse the content of the [`textProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#textProperty--) of the `TextField` instead:

```
int savedValue = Integer.parseInt(userInput.getText());
```